# Origin of mechanical work before work energy theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am interested to know when and why was the concept of mechanical work (W=F.s) introduced? What was the motivation behind it/ why was it considered meaningful before the work energy theorem?

Thankyou

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that it was [Gaspard Gustave de Coriolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspard-Gustave_de_Coriolis) who introduced the concept of mechanical work in his *Calcul de l'Effet des Machines*  of 1829.  His motivation appears to be the application of mechanics to industry.  The New World Encyclopedia entry [Mechanical Work](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Mechanical_work) provides some addition information.